# How to set printer specific info on all sheets in workbook

Tags: microsoft-excel, printing

We have a 53 page workbook in excel. It is instructed to print this in greyscale and with one page per sheet of paper. The only way I have been able to accomplish this is this way:

1. I select the pages I need to print
2. select print preview
3. press page setup
4. select options... from the dialog.
5. Then on the printers own printer dialog i select one sided and greyscale.
6. press ok
7. go to next page... and repeat

This is kind of tiresome, and I also notice that the printer settings is set for that page also for the future. So I know that excel can store the printer options.

So how can I tell excel to print the whole workbook with the same options.

Please do not tell me to select all sheets, then selecting page settings, and set the options. This doesn't work. Somehow the press on "options..." and editing the printer dialog does only affect the selected page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try publishing as (or printing to) a PDF file and then set the greyscale and one-sided settings when printing the PDF.

Comment: That is a workaround that might work, but I would prefer a way that makes Excel do what I want, and not have to rely on a two-step method.

Answer (score 0):

Write a VBA routine to loop through your wb and apply the settings.

Easy way to write it is to record your actions on one sheet, and modify the resulting code to loop through all sheets

Comment: Can it really be that hard to do something as simple as setting settings for how to print a document? Programming ability should be a precondition for doing such a ordinary action in a mainstream program. - I might do this, if no better suggestions shows up.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is an old post, but someone else may want to know.

In the print dialog box Print Range select Entire workbook

Excel 2003 looks like this

[image]

Excel 2010 may not be as apparent because it is a select with all choices not visible unless you click the dropdown immediately below "Settings"

[image]

Comment: This doesn't actually solve the issue.  When you try this, it only applies the option for the first page, then starts printing double sided for the rest (this issue was never resolved for Excel 2010).  This is the primary issue OP is running into.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit amazed at the way that this problem continues to perplex, or at least annoy. I assumed there'd be some easy fix, but of the options above I found printing to a PDF file, then printing from that the easiest.
Then it occurred to me to use Libreoffice, and there's no problem. It just prints the pages as one print job with the same settings for all. Unfortunately import/export will give rise to minor changes in formatting, so check the doc before sending it off.